# Connect hazelcast client to Management Center

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have connected hazelcast server to mancenter using following configuration

```
@Bean

 public Config mancenterConfig() 
 {

Config cfg = new Config();
   cfg.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        cfg.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5705).setPortAutoIncrement(false);
        cfg.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true).addMember("127.0.0.1");
        cfg.getNetworkConfig().getInterfaces().setEnabled(true).addInterface("127.0.0.*");
        cfg.getManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(true).setUrl("http://localhost:8080/mancenter");
        return cfg;

   }
```

But I don't know how to set Management Center Url in Client Configuration

```
@Bean
public ClientConfig getClientConfig() {

ClientConfig clientConfig= new ClientConfig();

ClientNetworkConfig clientNetworkConfig = new ClientNetworkConfig();

clientConfig.setNetworkConfig(clientNetworkConfig);
        return clientConfig;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on later versions of Hazelcast, 3.9 and up, but in a different manner,

Hazelcast Clients don't *directly* connect to the Management Center, so the management center location isn't appropriate for the client's configuration.

Instead, if you set the property `hazelcast.client.statistics.enabled` to true, then the Hazelcast Client will pass it's statistics to the Hazelcast Server which will pass these statistics on to the Management Center.

Comment: I set the property  as  --clientConfig.setProperty("hazelcast.client.statistics.enabled", "true"); but it doesn't works for me. Is there another way to set the property

Comment: Try it as a system property as part of your Java start-up? Get it working first, then find the place where it suits your style to set it.

Comment: ie `java -Dhazelcast.client.statistics.enabled=true -jar ...`